# How can I disable a button only if specific Input is empty?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, button, disable

I've tried to find a way to disable a button only if specific Inputs fields are still empty.
I mean that only few Inputs fields are required for the process, and some are only optional.

The course which I take show us how to disable the button until every input is valid, so I'm not sure what to do.

This is my code, I want the button to be disable only if date is empty.

```
<form className="place-form" onSubmit={placeSubmitHandler}>
    <Input
    id="date"
    element="input"
    type="date"
    label="Date"
    validators={[VALIDATOR_REQUIRE()]}
    errorText=""
    onInput={inputHandler}
  />

  <Input
    id="description"
    element="textarea"
    label="description"
    validators={[VALIDATOR_MINLENGTH(5)]}
    errorText=""
    onInput={inputHandler}
  />
      

  <Button type="submit" disabled={ formState.isValid  }>
     Sumbit
  </Button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put `Not sign like !` before `formState.isValid`

```
<Button type="submit" disabled={ !formState.isValid  }>
     Sumbit
  </Button>
```

I have prepared a sample using `react-hook-form`. you can check this here:

**WORKING DEMO**

[image: Edit #SO-material-onclick-edit]

Comment: But then I have to input in both fields in order to press the button

Comment: I have prepared a sample. please check working demo

Comment: You are welcome :)